# Object doesnt contain definition of Selected in CheckListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to count number of checkboxlist items that's being checked and if count is more than 3 I would provide an message saying cant accept more than 3 votes .

But I am unable to get the specific understanding why this **Selected** error is persisting

```
private void loadCandidates()
{
    //   int count = countCandidates();

    String qry = "SELECT * FROM candidate_tb WHERE party ='Samagi Jana Balawegaya'";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            String no = (rd["no"].ToString());
            checklist.Items.Add("Candidate NO:" + "" + no);

            checklist.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            checklist.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(163, 221, 203);
            checklist.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
            checklist.Width = 500;
            this.checklist.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checklist_Click);
        }

        FLP.Controls.Add(checklist);
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Internal error: {es}");
    }
}

private void checklist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < checklist.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (checklist.Items[i].Selected) // **ERROR**
        {
            count++;
        }
        
    }
    MessageBox.Show($"{count}");
}
```

Comment: `checklist.Items.Add("Candidate NO:" + "" + no)` means you are adding strings to the Items collection. How is a string supposed to have a `Selected` property? Besides that, `Items[i]` returns an `object` which must be cast to to appropriate type.

Comment: Instead of a Click event handler, you should perhaps implement a handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: The use of BorderStyle and BackColor indicates that this is WinForms code. So I removed the WPF tag from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checklist.Items[i]` is just an `object`. It doesn't have any properties.

However CheckedListBox has [GetSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.getselected?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_GetSelected_System_Int32_) method:

```
if (checklist.GetSelected(i))
{
    count++;
}
```